# Where to ask questions about Complexity Theory?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What would be the best SE site to ask about topics from the book *[Complexity: the Emerging Science at the Edge of Order and Chaos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671872346)*?

There is a sort of '[complexity theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory)' in computer science but I think this is a different topic.

Book description helps to explain why this is a little hard to place...:

> "Why did the stock market crash more than 500 points on a single
>   Monday in 1987? Why do ancient species often remain stable in the
>   fossil record for millions of years and then suddenly disappear? In a
>   world where nice guys often finish last, why do humans value trust and
>   cooperation? At first glance these questions don't appear to have
>   anything in common, but in fact every one of these statements refers
>   to a complex system. The science of complexity studies how single
>   elements, such as a species or a stock, spontaneously organize into
>   complicated structures like ecosystems and economies; stars become
>   galaxies, and snowflakes avalanches almost as if these systems were
>   obeying a hidden yearning for order.
>
> Drawing from diverse fields,
>   scientific luminaries such as Nobel Laureates Murray Gell-Mann and
>   Kenneth Arrow are studying complexity at a think tank called The Santa
>   Fe Institute. The revolutionary new discoveries researchers have made
>   there could change the face of every science from biology to cosmology
>   to economics. M. Mitchell Waldrop's groundbreaking bestseller takes
>   readers into the hearts and minds of these scientists to tell the
>   story behind this scientific revolution as it unfolds."

Answer (score 2):

You have a question about complex systems. This is a research field in Computer Science, and is different from "Big Oh" complexity theory.

We don't know what your question is, but the book sounds popular-scientific (with, apparently, an emphasis on "popular"). So it's presumably a theoretical question, making it on-topic on [Theoretical Computer Science SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

FWIW, that site also has a [question about the difference between Complexity Theory and the study of complex systems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3103/47463).

Make sure your question is well researched and shows some understanding of the basics - cstheory.SE has a high bar, or so I've been told.